# App icon contents.json file getting "corrupted"

Tags: ios, xcode

I have or I had a few app icon folders in my project which were working fine and the next day I try to open it and it says `The Contents.json describing the image set "AppIcon.appiconset" must start with a top level dictionary.`

The only things I've changed on my computer between the two instances is update my OS to 10.10.4

I have tried deleting the previous app icon folders and adding new ones and still doesn't work. When I create a new app icon folder the empty thumbnails disappear after showing up on the screen for a few seconds.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 10.4.4?  Really?  Or 10.10.4, maybe?

Comment: yes, 10.10.4 i meant

Comment: changed it.. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: anyone? I can't even submit my binary to the app store...

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Text tab

Uncheck 'Smart quotes and dashes' and select the last option in the 'for Double Quotes' drop down menu.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My situation may have been slightly different.  I recently merged code from a branch into the main.  I then created a new branch.  When I did so, I received that an error that my app icon contents.json wasn't well formed.  I use the local GIT repository.  With the most recent version of uploading projects, a 1024x1024 app icon is required.  I'm on Xcode version Version 9.0 (9A235).  When I inspected the contents.json file, I saw.

```
<<<<<<< 2.120
     "size" : "1024x1024",
     "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
     "filename" : "MyToyBox_Logo_5_1024.jpg",
=======
     "idiom" : "ios-marketing",
     "size" : "1024x1024",
>>>>>>> local
     "scale" : "1x"
}
```

it appears that the merge updated the file.  I deleted the data with the <<< and === and >>> and the duplicate lines.

I closed and re-opened Xcode and everything worked as expected.